# ASP.NET MVC + Angular app with only token auth and no cookie

Tags: angularjs, asp.net-mvc, cookies, asp.net-identity, identityserver3

I have an application built by a previous developer that uses OWIN middleware with both cookie and OAuth tokens.  It is an ASP.NET MVC app that is only using MVC views/controllers for login and a home view that hosts an entirely separate Angular app.

Bearer tokens are used to authenticate to the API once the app is entirely loaded but an auth cookie is used to load the initial scaffold MVC home view enclosing the ng app.

My issue is having a business requirement to allow users to login with unique credentials per browser tab therefore **cookies cannot be used** but simply use a session-based token to keep them separate.

**Can an ASP.NET MVC app fundamentally operate without cookie-based auth?**

If I can remove cookie auth and rely on tokens only this will solve my issue of having to rewrite the angular outer frame in solely angular code and reimplement login pathway.

A note: I am implementing IdentityServer3 and I found all samples there and elsewhere always have cookie auth as part of the mix thus my question here.

Comment: Get rid of the MVC part and make it a JS only app.

Answer (score 0):

I think what you want to do here is the following:

1. Add an [AllowAnonymous] on the Home controller
2. In the application that is loaded by the Home page, use a browser side package like oidc-client to perform a user login. This will return an id and an access token.
3. Inject the access token in you REST service requests.
4. Use UseIdentityServerBearerTokenAuthentication to filter and authenticate bearer tokens in the WEB API server.